# CSS: paragraph in div to appear on same line as div text

Tags: html, css

How can I get "Current data: " and whatever value the #dataset_name paragraph takes to appear on one line?

```
<div id="current_data">Current dataset: <p id="dataset_name"></p></div>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
<div id="current_data">Current dataset: <span id="dataset_name"></span></div>
```

Spans are, by default, `inline` elements, `p` and `div` are `block` elements (therefore, they add a "newline"). You could also use `<p style="display: inline;">...</p>`, but it's better to use `span` in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` elements are considered blocks by HTML while normal text is inline.

In your CSS put:

```
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

and you'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
<p id="current_data">Current dataset: <span id="dataset_name"></span></p>
```

It makes more semantical sense (as long as its not really a table).